Confusing artifact in an electrically-stimulated compound action potential of the nerve
The condition is that the nerve has been pinched (essentially destroyed so no action potential gets conducted along the nerve) and then is being electrically stimulated to produce action potentials. Stimulus voltage is 60V.
I get this weird bump (like a decaying sine wave) in the compound action potential trace after the shock artifact instead of a flat line.
At stimulus voltages like 30V, I get the flat line like shown below. 
What could be the explanation for this? Please help.

I think it's probably a stimulus artifact that's ringing through your equipment. Basically it's too strong of a stimulus relative to your setup. You might try a dummy setup e.g. saline with agar and try to replicate it.

Thank you Bryan. I will definitely try that. But do you have any suggestions for getting just a "normal" stimulus artifact at higher stimulus voltages? I was thinking it was something to do with the suction recording electrode that I have.

You might need electrodes with lower impedance/resistance, and/or a better ground. But you also might just be putting too much juice through your amplifier relative to the size of signals you record.
